# Need help setting up a router to extend existing network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I purchased TP-Link AXE5400 which I plan to use in my office.  I want the router to have physical devices and wifi devices as an extension of my office LAN.  I want to offer a Guest Wifi for my clients but not allow them access to my LAN.

I tried to configure this new router in AP Mode and it seems that the Guest Network in AP Mode does not isolate the LAN and Guest Wifi. I have been reading that the TP-Link routers will not isolate the networks within AP Mode and instead it has to be set up in Router mode.

Question:  How do I configure things as an extension of my existing network while in Router mode for both wired and wireless devices?

I'm thinking that I connect the Router to my existing switch via Port 1,2,3,4 rather than using the WAN port. I understand that this will extend the physical devices.

But...  How do I set up the wifi access to also be an extension of the existing network?  Won't the router automatically assign DHCP IP addresses?  Can I set it up so my existing network/DHCP server assigns the IP addresses for all wired and wireless devices?

I would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: I assume by "extension of the existing network" you mean you want the devices to _seamlessly_ move between the two routers? (While the combination of AP+guest modes you want is possible in general, I really suspect the TP-Link firmware just doesn't offer it.)

Comment: Note that having a "child" subnet (and an additional layer of NAT) does not mean the hosts in the "parent" subnet would be "safer". You would need some kind of firewalling if security is your goal, and normally consumer-grade router (I mean like the non-"wrt" ones.) does not offer this kind of customizable firewall which allows you to block e.g. non-Internet-destined traffics.

Comment: (Even if a router has so-to-speak "guest" SSID that isolate clients from its main SSID/LAN, it will not help if what you want to "protect" is an "outer" router's LAN, because that would be just part of the WAN from the POV of the "inner" router. One possible exception though is that it could be blocking all private-IP-destined traffics from going out to the WAN, but you'll need to test to see if it actually implement anything like that.)